# SQL to get only amount (number after $ sign) and percentage (numbers before % sign) from a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some rule descriptions as below, let's say in table1

```
rule_id   rule_desc
F89   Ded2 + $100 Copay + 20% Coins; $750 Max + $250 Penalty
F70   Ded1+$250Copay+50%;Upto $500 max+50%Penalty
```

What I would like to get from above two example is that..

```
For F89,
Copay = 100
Coins = 20
Max = 750
Penalty = 250
```

And for F70,

```
Copay = 250
Coins = 50
Max = 500
Penalty = 0.5 (50/100)
```

Can someone please help on this to write a SQL query (I use Oracle SQL Developer), I am find getting the result in multiple rows or separate columns for Copay, Coins, Max and Penalty, please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: I'd do that as a post-processing step in Perl/Java/Ruby/Python/whatever. That the "syntax" of your rule description seems to be quite loose will not make this easy ...

Comment: Few more information I would like to add is that, Copay amount is always mentioned before the test "Copay", similarly others as well except the Coins. Sometimes coins is mentioned without a text coins, so to differentiate between coins and percentage is that penalty percent or amount will be defined before the text "penalty". Also it is not mandatory that all these values will be there, sometimes description can be only "$50 Copay" or sometimes only "Ded1 + 20% Coins".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You requirements seems to be changing with every description. For the kind of data that you have provided and with certain assumptions this query may be helpful -

```
WITH tab(rule_id, rule_desc) AS 
  (SELECT 'F89', 'Ded2 + $100 Copay + 20% Coins; $750 Max + $250 Penalty' from dual union all
   SELECT 'F70', 'Ded1+$250Copay+50%;Upto $500 max+50%Penalty' FROM dual union all
   SELECT 'F71', '$50 Copay' FROM dual union all
   SELECT 'F72', 'Ded1 + 20% Coins' FROM dual),
-----------------------------------------------
---- End of data preparation
-----------------------------------------------
temp_table as (SELECT rule_id, REGEXP_SUBSTR (rule_desc,'[^\+|;]+',1,LEVEL) txt
                 FROM tab
              CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (rule_desc,'[^\+|;]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
                  AND PRIOR rule_desc = rule_desc
                  AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL),
final_table as (
SELECT RULE_ID, TXT,
       coalesce(REGEXP_SUBSTR(replace(TXT, 'Upto'), '[a-z,A-Z]+'), 'Coins') "KEY",
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(TXT, '[0-9]+') "VALUE",
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(TXT, '\W+') "SIGN"
  FROM temp_table)
SELECT RULE_ID,
       KEY ||'='||
       case when SIGN = '%' and KEY = 'Penalty' then
           to_char(VALUE / 100)
       else
           VALUE
       end STR
  FROM final_table
 WHERE key not in ('Ded');
```

Output :

```
| RULE_ID |         STR |
|---------|-------------|
|     F71 |    Copay=50 |
|     F72 |    Coins=20 |
|     F70 |   Copay=250 |
|     F70 |    Coins=50 |
|     F70 |     max=500 |
|     F70 |  Penalty=.5 |
|     F89 |   Copay=100 |
|     F89 |    Coins=20 |
|     F89 |     Max=750 |
|     F89 | Penalty=250 |
```

Assumtions:

1) Only missing key can be "Coins"

2) Percentage calculation is application for Penalty only.

3) Penalty KEY can have only "Upto" string that we have to replace. In this query, "Upto" will be removed from all the keys.

I am not sure it may help you, but I hope it will show you some way.